# How can I get an array of alternating values in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Simple question here:

I'm trying to get an array that alternates values (1, -1, 1, -1.....) for a given length.  np.repeat just gives me (1, 1, 1, 1,-1, -1,-1, -1).  Thoughts?

Comment: How about strides or views? Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I like @Benjamin's solution. An alternative though is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((15,))
a[::2] = 1
a[1::2] = -1
```

This also allows for odd-length lists.

**EDIT:** Also just to note speeds, for a array of 10000 elements

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer

if __name__ == '__main__':

    setupstr="""
import numpy as np
N = 10000
"""

    method1="""
a = np.empty((N,),int)
a[::2] = 1
a[1::2] = -1
"""

    method2="""
a = np.tile([1,-1],N)
"""

    method3="""
a = np.array([1,-1]*N)   
"""

    method4="""
a = np.array(list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle((1,-1)), N)))    
"""
    nl = 1000
    t1 = Timer(method1, setupstr).timeit(nl)
    t2 = Timer(method2, setupstr).timeit(nl)
    t3 = Timer(method3, setupstr).timeit(nl)
    t4 = Timer(method4, setupstr).timeit(nl)

    print 'method1', t1
    print 'method2', t2
    print 'method3', t3
    print 'method4', t4
```

Results in timings of:

```
method1 0.0130500793457
method2 0.114426136017
method3 4.30518102646
method4 2.84446692467
```

If `N = 100`, things start to even out but starting with the empty numpy arrays is still significantly faster (`nl` changed to 10000)

```
method1 0.05735206604
method2 0.323992013931
method3 0.556654930115
method4 0.46702003479
```

Numpy arrays are special awesome objects and should not be treated like python lists.

Comment: +1: This is quite fast, most likely the best way to do it with numpy.

Comment: You could also use a = np.ones(15) instead of empty and =1.

Comment: @DSM that's another possibility, but in my tests it's still a bit slower than the solution I posted (but still faster than everything else). I discovered this fill trick a while back and am still not sure why it is often faster than the more straightforward/intuitive solution. I'm a big fan of `timeit` since it is an objective arbiter .

Comment: @JoshAdel: Yes `timeit` is objective in some sense but remember that python is often written for simplicity and readability rather than speed alone! Especially if you don't have a real reason to optimize for CPU time or memory, I'd say stick with the more commonplace, readable solution such as a list comprehension or `cycle`: you and others may appreciate it in the future.

Comment: @machine yearning: I would argue that my solution is among the most readable and simple solutions presented. While I love itertools and list comprehensions, numpy has a set of very efficient methods built specifically to manipulate numpy arrays, and the numpythonic way is to use them.

Comment: @JoshAdel: Well I'll defer to you for that then, because I'm no numpy expert, but for the record it was the define/iterslice/reiterslice combo that bugged me, not the numpy function. I think `numpy.ones()` would be better just because you only have to slice the array once, which is more readable simply because it's only two statements and you're getting straight to the point. I agree that your solution is very readable and a clever one, that's why it got my upvote, but that doesn't mean it's perfect! :)

Answer (score 17):

use resize():

```
In [38]: np.resize([1,-1], 10) # 10 is the length of result array
Out[38]: array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1])
```

it can produce odd-length array:

```
In [39]: np.resize([1,-1], 11)
Out[39]: array([ 1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1])
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `numpy.tile`!

```
import numpy
a = numpy.tile([1,-1], 15)
```

Comment: Doesn't allow for odd-length lists

Comment: Lol not from me! Someone was just pissed off or something?

Answer (score 6):

use multiplication:

```
[1,-1] * n
```

Comment: Or `*(int)(n/2)` if you want n to be the length of list.

Comment: Doesn't allow for odd-length lists

Answer (score 6):

If you want a memory efficient solution, try this:

```
def alternator(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            yield 1
        else:
            yield -1
```

Then you can iterate over the answers like so:

```
for i in alternator(n):
    # do something with i
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'd imagine it's because it doesn't make sense to re-implement `itertools.islice(itertools.cycle((1,-1)), n)`.

Comment: +1 Well you get my upvote because it's original and efficient! It's always nice to see an original implementation of something in a library so you can see the inner workings of it. Could probably be a bit more general, but meh. Good job incorporating odd-length too. Definitely not worth a down-vote.

Comment: agf, that's yet another way. My implementation wasn't overly verbose, or overly terse, or wasteful, and showed the OP how to do things a bit differently. It wasn't dumb.

machine yearning: thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for itertools.cycle?

```
list_ = (1,-1,2,-2)  # ,3,-3, ...

for n, item in enumerate(itertools.cycle(list_)):
    if n==30:
        break

    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw these out there because they could be more useful in some circumstances.

If you just want to alternate between positive and negative:

```
[(-1)**i for i in range(n)]
```

or for a more general solution

```
nums = [1, -1, 2]
[nums[i % len(nums)] for i in range(n)]
```