# NumPy concat by turns

Tags: python, numpy

How to combine 2 arrays by turns from

```
arr_1 = np.full((5,), 0)
arr_2 = np.full((5,), 1)
```

to

```
[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: ```np.array(list(zip(arr_1, arr_2))).flatten()```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get an array of alternating values in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154739/how-can-i-get-an-array-of-alternating-values-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two arrays you can stack and then transpose them. Then just flatten it out:

```
import numpy as np

arr_1 = np.full((5,), 0)
arr_2 = np.full((5,), 1)

np.stack([arr_1, arr_2]).T.ravel()
#array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

This works by first stacking:

```
np.stack([arr_1, arr_2])
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Then transposing:

```
np.stack([arr_1, arr_2]).T
# array([[0, 1],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 1]])
```

Then `ravel()` reads them off the contiguous flattened array.

#### Edit

As Nin17 points out in the comments [`stack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) takes an `axis` argument, which avoids the transpose:

```
np.stack([arr_1, arr_2], 1).ravel()
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

This is a nice performance improvement.

Comment: you can use the axis argument of stack and avoid having to take the transpose: ```np.stack([arr_1, arr_2], 1).ravel()``` makes it significantly faster

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like so:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1])
repeated = np.tile(a, 5)
```

Result:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

[Documentation.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

Comment: this doesn't combine two arrays?

Comment: @Nin17 I'm trying to answer the implied XY question.